# PHPMyAdmin Duplicate rows of a table with the same data of each row, but with less digits of the primary key

Tags: mysql

I know my question is confusing. I have a table 'Pacchi'.

---

```
Scatola  Faldone  Descrizione  Ubicazione
Cg4      AQ-5877  NULL         Bottom
Cg4      AQ-5878  NULL         Bottom 
Cg5      AQ-5879  NULL         Bottom
Cg5      AQ-5880  NULL         Middle
```

---

The field 'Faldone' is the primary key, and the part of text of 'Faldone' after AQ is already univocal(Example. 5877).
I have to duplicate each row with the same fields, but the field 'Faldone' contains only the second part of the string

```
Scatola  Faldone  Descrizione  Ubicazione
Cg4      AQ-5877  NULL         Bottom
Cg4      AQ-5878  NULL         Bottom
Cg5      AQ-5879  NULL         Bottom
Cg5      AQ-5880  NULL         Middle
Cg4      5877     NULL         Bottom
Cg4      5878     NULL         Bottom
Cg5      5879     NULL         Bottom
Cg5      5880     NULL         Middle
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION :

```
select Scatola, Faldone, Descrizione, Ubicazione from Pacchi as a
UNION ALL
select Scatola, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Faldone, '-', -1) as Faldone, Descrizione, Ubicazione from Pacchi as b
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I should have also asked how to get the Substring of: 
Examples AQ-999AK-AC-FS (I only need 999AK)
                 AQ-999AJ-AC-FS (Need 999AJ)

Comment: Get at the 4th position a substring which has length = 5 : `SUBSTR(Faldone, 4, 5)` [check  here](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html). Please accepting the answer or updating if it works is very welcome ;)